# change the way of browser's rendering

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox

considering below example:

```
<table><tr><td><div type="label"></td></tr><table>
```

when this content parse by browsers they created the table with tr and td and inside td the div with "label" was created, I was wondering that is it possible to tell browser, when you faced with this kind of content instead of div just draw a label.

I can do this for instance replace div with label simply by regex functions by I want to find an approach that browser (e.g. Firefox) did this for or something better?

should I develop a Firefox plugin for this purpose or is it some easiest way exist to handle it?

thanks

Comment: How this markup is generated? Why don't you in first place use a LABEL? BTW, `type` attribute isn't valid attribute for DIV element. In jQuery, this would work: `$('table div[type=label]').replaceWith('<label/>');`

Comment: in fact, I try to create my own form generator and I wanted this replacement taken place before rendering, the page that was written based on this declaration has many other divations an each one has its own type (e.g. label, multiselect, combobox, lov, ...)

Comment: So why do you use DIVs? I don't get it